# how implement a Random function in prolog?

Tags: random, prolog

I try to implement a random function because random (1) does not work in Ciao Prolog System  . Anyone could help me make a function that returns random values ​​from a list.

Comment: you know there's a module in ciao?  http://ciaohome.org/docs/branches/1.14/13646/CiaoDE-1.14.2-13646_ciao.html/random.html

Answer (score 0):

If you want a Number between Low and Up, try [random](http://ciaohome.org/docs/branches/1.14/13646/CiaoDE-1.14.2-13646_ciao.html/random.html#random/1)/3:

```
random(Low,Up,Number)
```

Comment: I try to implements this function,random :S because  this function not work in ciao.